# Recursively delete empty directories in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line

I have a directory on my Windows 7 machine that has hundreds if not thousands of sub-directories.  Some of them have files, some do not.  I want to delete all the empty directories.

Looking at the del and rmdir DOS command, it does not look like you can recursively do this without deleting all the files.  Is there a way to do this from the command line?

Comment: I am amazed there's no simple answer to this question.

Comment: @billpg: simple as it could get: `xcopy FROMDIR TODIR /s`. See this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14742810

Comment: XCOPY deletes directories?

Comment: It can be done easily using ROBOCOPY. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You can use [Remove Empty Directories](http://www.jonasjohn.de/lab/red.htm) utility.

Alternatively you can use this one-liner batch file (from [DownloadSquad](https://web.archive.org/web/20100328155520/http://www.downloadsquad.com/2008/05/05/automatically-delete-empty-subdirectories-with-one-line-batch-fi)):

```
for /f "delims=" %d in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%d"
```

(if used inside a batch file, replace `%d` with `%%d`)

This works because `rd` will not remove a directory that contains files.

Comment: P.S I suggest you try the GUI-based tool first, before trying any command-line commands that can potentially delete all files.

Comment: that tool looks good.  I will check it out and report back

Comment: Using the batch version gives me an error: The system cannot find the file dir /ad/b/s | sort /R.

Comment: Hang on, testing command in my Windows VM.

Comment: Also the batch version would not handle spaces in the directory names. I'm pretty sure that it would not remove a directory that contained only empty sub directories either.

Comment: Got it, couple of errors with the DownloadSquad's command (!!). I've amended in my answer. :)

Comment: Still won't delete a directory that contains an empty directory.

Comment: Make sure it is truly empty. A hidden desktop.ini is still considered a file. same as a thumbs.db. If you want to verify whether this works, create a test directory with directories inside that are empty and populated. It works, I've verified.

Comment: Yep. It works. My mistake.

Comment: for /f %d in ('dir /s/b') do rmdir "%d" should work as rmdir cannot remove a non-empty folder

Comment: RED is the best tool for this, since it handles directories with nothing but junk in them (Thumbs.db, .DS_Store), lets you permanently protect directories from deletion, shows a nice tree view, etc. I got it working in Windows 7 using the compatibility troubleshooter thing.  There's also a list of alternative tools at the bottom of the RED web site.

Comment: This doesn't work if the folder is set to read only.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/34025977/694360 to find out how to add this functionality to context menu.

Comment: The for loop command worked perfectly.

Comment: Just a warning, this script destroys directory junctions too. I learned this the hard way.

Comment: @Pyroglyph: Can you edit the answer (I don't fully understand what this means)?

Comment: I get this error: "sort: cannot read: /r: No such file or directory" UPDATE: Ah, my cmd is using Git-for-Windows' `git\usr\bin\sort.exe` instead of `system32\sort.exe).

Answer (score 100):

You can also use ROBOCOPY. It is very simple and can also be used to delete empty folders inside large hierarchy.

```
ROBOCOPY folder1 folder1 /S /MOVE
```

Here both source and destination are `folder1`, as you only need to delete empty folders, instead of moving other files to different folder. `/S` option is to skip copying(moving, in the above case) empty folders. It is also faster as the files are moved inside the same drive.

Comment: Magic. So this moves all non-empty folders to the very same location they were already in (so does  nothing?), and skips empty folders? But then: why would skipping them result in deletion? And wouldn't this move nested folders into `folder1`? Scary, unless tested well.

Comment: @Arjan I have tested it, and it works perfectly!. To understand its working, its like moving all files to different location, except empty folders, and then deleting the left-behind empty-folders. `/MOVE` copies the files first, and then deletes the source file after copying. So, as `/S` is used, it copies the non-empty folders to destination(same folder in the above case). Then, it deletes the empty folders(like, its thinking that empty-folders has already been copied). No, it **does not** move nested folders into `folder1`, as ROBOCOPY moves folders recursively.

Comment: it even works with UNC paths (at least on win7) ! Brilliant !

Comment: Can Robocopy move files to the recycle bin?

Comment: This is a very elegant solution without any third-party software needed. Thank you!

Comment: This just did its magic and worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Varun thanks. This is an awesome solution. Went through 3.8TB of files across 60,000 folders in about 10 minutes. Not a single file lost, but no more empty directories. Beautiful.

Comment: LOVE IT robocopy.exe are in win8 or win10 :  ROBOCOPY %temp% %temp% /S /MOVE  and its clean my temp from e,pty folders who

Comment: This is fantastic. A couple notes; first this correctly solves a reported problem with the accepted answer where directories containing only empty directories would not be removed. It's not trivial to fix in that approach because it requires removal in *depth-first order*. This `robocopy` technique fully removes empty structures to any level of depth. Second, it's worth mentioning that *no files are actually moved* by `robocopy` here. This is important for performance of course, but it also means that no NTFS file identifier (FRN) numbers or USN journals are unnecessarily changed or recorded.

Comment: I think Robocopy requires folder names with spaces to be enclosed in double quotes, and backslashes in path names to be replaced with double backslashes.

Comment: Be careful of junctions, directory links, file links, etc... they will be followed and can cause some unexpected results. When running it on a Windows Users folder from another drive, be ware of the Music, Documents, Videos links etc.

Comment: This is is one of my all-time most revisited stackexchange answers thank you!!

Comment: This saved me so much time when trying to clear an important folder containing hundreds of thousands of empty folders plus a handful of important, non-empty folders in between. For performance reasons I added the switches to not output to the console, and robocopy blazed like a flaming torch through the job: /NFL /NDL /NJH /NJS

Answer (score 18):

Since Cygwin comes with GNU find, you can do this:

```
find . -type d -empty -delete
```

Or to avoid the noise when a folder no longer exists:

```
find . -type d -empty -execdir rmdir {} +
```

Comment: This can also now be done using Windows 10 Bash.

Comment: For my install of Windows 10 this (`find . -type d -empty -delete`) fails from the command prompt with the following error: `FIND: Parameter format not correct`

Comment: It works in `Git Bash` also

Answer (score 7):

The free utility [EmptyFolderNuker](https://web.archive.org/web/20161216200438/http://simonwai.com:80/developments/empty_folder_nuker/) does this fine, from a base folder of your choice. It also removes those directories only containing empty sub-directories.

Comment: The one-liner batch file didn't work for me (I get the error "%%d was unexpected at this time."), and the Remove Empty Directories program will not install (it says on the linked page that it is not compatible with Windows 7 anyway).

This program worked like a charm.

Comment: As user36580 wrote below, "it is likely you are running directly from the command line. In that case, change the double %% to a single %"

Comment: I like this over the pure command-line version as it allows you to preview the things that get deleted. You can always call it from the command-line using `"%~dp0\EmptyFolderNuker.exe" %cd%`.

Comment: @rob-kam The URL for "EmptyFolderNuker" isn't available anymore.

Comment: @PeterCo Thanks, fixed now.

Answer (score 7):

Hmmm...  maybe even simpler solution:

`for /d /r %d in (*.*) do rd "%d"`

Start this from the folder you want empty folders to be deleted.

/d - will work on folders, not files
/r - will recurse subdirs

Comment: Thanks. Found that this only applies to commandline not batchfiles. According to https://superuser.com/questions/444474/how-to-delete-empty-folders-from-a-given-directory-in-windows-with-a-script by Dennis, if we want to use this in a batchfile it should be `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%i"`. The `for` behaviour is slightly different between commandline and batchfiles.

Comment: This does not work for me when I have nested empty folders. I think it starts at the top of the hierarchy, so the folders aren't empty. You could just run it repeatedly until it gets them all, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) installed, you could do this:

```
find -type d -exec rmdir {} \;
```

Comment: Not necessarily. That might not delete directories with only empty subdirectories. You might have to reverse it.

    find -type d -print0 | tac | xargs -0 rmdir

Comment: I never knew about "tac" before.  That's really nifty!

Comment: Or use `find ` *`(starting-directory) `* **`-depth `** `-type d ...`.  The `-depth` option tells `find` to do something like reverse the order of the output — it goes to the deepest directory levels first, then works its way back up.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working in emacs (making this platform-agnostic), the following works:

```lisp
(defun *-delete-empty-directories (root-directory)
  "Recursively delete empty directories in ROOT-DIRECTORY.

When called from dired, `dired-current-directory' is used for
ROOT-DIRECTORY."

  ;; Interface
  (interactive (list (if (eq major-mode 'dired-mode)
                         (expand-file-name (dired-current-directory))
                       (read-from-minibuffer "Root directory: "))))
  (when (or (null root-directory) (string= "" root-directory))
    (user-error "No root directory provided"))
  (when (called-interactively-p 'interactive)
    (unless (yes-or-no-p (format "Delete all non-empty directories in `%s'? "
                                 root-directory))
      (user-error "Directory `%s' has been left untouched" root-directory)))

  ;; Implementation
  (require 'f)
  (let ((entries (f-directories root-directory)))
    (while entries
      (let ((curdir (car entries)))
        (when (f-directories curdir)
          (*-delete-empty-directories curdir))
        (unless (f-entries curdir)
          (delete-directory curdir)
          (message "Directory deleted: `%s'" curdir))
        (setq entries (cdr entries)))))
```

Comment: ...Please tell me you wouldn't have to type all of this in order to accomplish this in emacs.

Comment: @Hashim The idea is that you have it defined in your init and then bound to a key. Technically I could have it bound to `D` if I wanted to, but since I don't have a common need for this, all I have to type is `M-x *ded RET` and bam–done. (If I did indeed have to type this every time, you're absolutely right that it'd be absurd – luckily that's not the case.)

Comment: Fair enough, that sounds more plausible.

Comment: Does `M-x *ded RET` have any significance or is it random? If the latter, how do you keep track of all the shortcuts you've assigned in `emacs`? Does memorisation suffice or do you find yourself having to look them up?

Comment: @Hashim `*ded` is an abbreviation for the full function name `*-delete-empty-directories`. Many completion engines (such as ivy, the one I use) understand this kind of fuzzy matching. As for keeping them memorized… I simply don't have to. The functions I've defined all start with `*` so I can easily find them if they're not bound to a key. Otherwise, emacs itself will tell me if there was a faster way of calling the function. If all else fails, there's always `apropos`.

Comment: Can the downvoter please describe what should be improved upon in this answer? It's a valid approach.

Answer (score 0):

Combining Gareth's and G-Man's posts:

```
find . -depth -type d -empty -execdir rmdir {} +
```

Edit:
But that gave a security error because of 'C' in my PATH var...so instead:

```
$find . -depth -type d -empty | while read dir; do (rmdir -v $dir); done
```

I don't use xargs because it appears to have an input line limit (of about 1024 lines, I think?), whereas

```
 while read x; do (command $x); done
```

just keeps on going for as long as it has input. Leave out the '-v' verbose flag if you don't want to see the results and/or want it to run faster.

Answer (score 0):

None of the previous answers worked for me, so I made the following file:

```
EmptyDirectoriesRemove.cmd
```

Contents:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

:walk_tree
for /D %%d in (*) do (
cd %%d
@CALL :walk_tree %%d
cd ..
rd %%d
)

endlocal
```

Usage: Cd to the top level directory you want to clean up.  From the command line prompt, run:

> EmptyDirectoriesRemove.cmd

Warnings will show up for non-empty directories.

Usual disclaimers: Use at your risk.  Backup before testing. etc.

Answer (score 0):

The 4NT shell (nowadays Take Command) has a /sx option to "DEL".  /S is recursive, the appended X is remove empty dirs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem "Path" -recurse | 
  Where-Object {($_.PSIsContainer -eq $true) -and ((gci $_.fullName).count -eq 0)} | 
    Remove-Item -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use vbscript to do this:

```
' Save in deleteEmptyFolders.vbs
' call with:
' cscript deleteEmptyFolders.vbs C:\RootFolder
If WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then
  directory = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
  WSH.Echo("Deleting empty folders starting from " & directory)
Else
  WSH.Echo "Please supply a directory as an argument"
  WSH.Quit
End If

Set ofso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set rootFolder = ofso.GetFolder(directory)

Sub DeleteEmptySubfoldersIn(folder)
  For Each subfolder in folder.SubFolders
    On Error Resume Next '' VBScript TRY
    ' The script can error out if you don't have permissions to delete
    ' the subfolder
    DeleteEmptySubfoldersIn subfolder
  Next
  
  ''WScript.Echo folder.Path
  If folder.Files.Count = 0 And folder.SubFolders.Count = 0 Then
    'TEST: print what you'll delete
    WScript.Echo "Was going to delete " & folder.Path & " b/c it's EMPTY"

    'DISARMED uncomment line below to make it work
    '''''ofso.DeleteFolder folder
  End If
End Sub

DeleteEmptySubfoldersIn rootFolder
```

Answer (score 0):

### To delete empty folders while excluding hidden files

To delete empty folders while excluding hidden files using the command prompt (cmd), you can use a combination of the `dir`, `for`, and `rd` commands in Windows. Here's a step-by-step guide:

1. Open Command Prompt: Press `Win + R`, type `cmd`, and hit Enter.
2. Navigate to the directory where you want to start the deletion process. You can use the `cd` command to change directories. For example:

   ```
   cd "C:\Your\Directory\Path"
   ```
3. Run the following command to delete empty directories while excluding hidden files:

   ```
   for /f "delims=" %d in ('dir /ad /b /s ^| sort /r') do @(dir /a-d /b "%d" | findstr "." >nul || rd /s /q "%d")
   ```

This command will recursively search for all directories (`/ad`), list them (`/b` for bare format), and sort them in reverse order (`/s` for recursive, `sort /r` to reverse). Then, for each directory found, it checks if it contains any files (excluding hidden files) using `dir /a-d` and `findstr "."`. If no non-hidden files are found, it deletes the directory using `rd /s /q`.

Remember to replace `C:\Your\Directory\Path` with the actual path of the directory you want to clean up. And as always, be cautious when deleting files and folders, as this operation is irreversible. Make sure you have a backup of important data before proceeding.

---

### To delete empty folders while including hidden files

To delete empty folders while including hidden files, you can use a similar approach but modify the command to include hidden files as well. Here's how you can do it:

```
for /f "delims=" %d in ('dir /ad /b /s ^| sort /r') do @(dir /a /b "%d" | findstr "^" >nul || rd /s /q "%d")
```

This command will delete empty directories while including hidden files in the check for emptiness. Here's what each part of the command does:

- `for /f "delims=" %d in ('dir /ad /b /s ^| sort /r') do`: This loop iterates over all directories (`/ad`) recursively (`/s`) in bare format (`/b`) sorted in reverse order (`sort /r`).
- `dir /a /b "%d"`: Lists all files and directories, including hidden ones (`/a`), in the specified directory (`"%d"`) in bare format (`/b`).
- `findstr "^" >nul`: This command checks if any files or directories are found in the specified directory. If nothing is found, it outputs nothing (redirected to `nul`), indicating that the directory is empty.
- `rd /s /q "%d"`: Deletes the specified directory (`"%d"`) recursively (`/s`) without prompting (`/q`) if it's empty.

Make sure to replace `C:\Your\Directory\Path` with the actual path of the directory you want to clean up. As always, exercise caution when deleting files and folders, especially with recursive commands, and ensure you have a backup of important data.