# How to delete empty folders from a given directory in windows with a script

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

I'm using [r.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/) as a build tool but as of today that tools doesn't give me the ability to delete empty folders in the build dir. I've found these two scripts

```
for /f "usebackq" %%d in ("dir /ad/b/s | sort /R") do rd "%%d"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%i">NUL
```

looking around the net but i always get

```
%%i was unexpected at this time.
```

or

```
%%d was unexpected at this time.
```

And i wouldn't know how to tell the script where my directory is.

My build script is

```
@echo off
where /q r.js || (
    echo requirejs node package is not installed. You must install node, npm and then run npm install -g requirejs
    goto :eof
)
node r.js -o app.build.js
:end
```

I need to tell the script to remove all empty directories which are located inside `../../js`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reason I never fully understood, `for` uses a different syntax inside and outside of batch files.

This command should work inside a batch file

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%i"
```

In the command prompt (no batch file), you have to substitute `%%i` by `%i`:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%i"
```

Also, to suppress the `The directory is not empty.` error messages, use `rd "%i" 2>NUL`.

A simple `rd "%i">NUL` redirects the output ([stdout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29)), not the error messages ([stderr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29)).

Comment: This works perfectly. If i wanted to suppress all ( both output and error)  messages how should i do?

Comment: Just use both: `rd "%i">NUL 2>NUL`. In this case, `>NUL` is not needed, since `rd` doesn't produce any output.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the first script, i.e., the one below, *DOES NOT work on directories with space characters*.

```
for /f "usebackq" %%d in ("dir /ad/b/s | sort /R") do rd "%%d"
```

The correct version should be here. Note that the use of the default spaces and tabs as delimiters MUST be disabled.

```
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%d in ("dir /ad/b/s | sort /R") do rd "%%d"
```

And please refer to Dennis's answer (the accepted one) for using the script on command prompt.

Comment: You don't need `"usebackq"` unless the command in `(...)` is using  `\``, yours is using `"`.

Comment: In addition `usebackqdelims` is invalid, there should be a space like `usebackq delims`