# Deleting empty folders and subfolders in windows cmd prompt

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

As the title mentions I need a command to delete empty folders and subfolders in windows cmd promptwith the caveat that a folder containing one or several subfolders which are empty should also be deleted. I found the following [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/444474/how-to-delete-empty-folders-from-a-given-directory-in-windows-with-a-script?newreg=813f51583ee74b6b94d799635cc28327) and the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/444479/1766754) by Dennis seems to be exactly what I need and seems to work:

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir myDrive:\myPath /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%i"
```

However, I don't get those: `^|`. There is most likely a documentation about it but I could not find it... So I would be very happy with some explanation or a link towards the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20342902/)

> The ^ symbol (also called caret or circumflex) is an escape character in Batch script. When it is used, the next character is interpreted as an ordinary character.

also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20349777/)

> the entire line `for /f "delims=" %i in ('dir myDrive:\myPath /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%i"` must be parsed by the batch parser before it can pass the `('dir myDrive:\myPath /s /b /ad ^| sort /r')` clause on to be executed. Without the <kbd>^</kbd>, the <kbd>|</kbd> confuses the batch parser. The <kbd>^</kbd> escapes (protects) the pipe during the initial batch parsing.

<sup>**Note:** *Quoted `code` above was updated to (replaced with) `code` from [your own question](https://superuser.com/q/1764613/)*</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was very helpful.