# Tag issue with sort used for recursively delete empty directories in Windows

Tags: windows-10, command-line

The accepted solution to the question 
[Recursively delete empty directories in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/39674/recursively-delete-empty-directories-in-windows)

```
for /f "delims=" %d in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%d"
```

doesn't work due to the miss-interpretation of the tag '/R' ( returned error message : sort: cannot read: /R: No such file or directory )

Anyone can explain why ?

Comment: Work around use 'sort --reverse' instead of 'sort /r'

Comment: Are you on windows 7?

Comment: No on windows 10 Pro

Comment: Works fine here on Windows 10 Pro.  Typos?  Corrupt file system perhaps?