# Windows Explorer.exe crashes when running a cmd command from shell registry

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-explorer, cmd.exe, windows-registry

I saw this nice cmd command [on this SU answer](https://superuser.com/a/39679/920525) that removes empty folders in a one liner. I thought this would be very useful to have as a right click context-menu option for folders.

So I went over to "Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell" on the registry and added a key with a name and another command key underneath that with default value set to `cmd.exe /s /c "for /f "delims=" %d in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%d""`.

I see the contextmenu option when I right click a folder, and when I click on the menu option, no cmd window opens and Explorer.exe restarts. The command works fine when I manually execute it in cmd though.

Why does this command not work when hit from a folder right-click contextmenu while it does work on it's own? It especially doesn't make sense to me that Explorer.exe crashes as a result of this.

Comment: You aren't actually asking a question, but rather stating a fact, though I can guess the question you wanted to ask(but didn't ask) is:How to make the command run in shell script? It can take multiple steps, but first, try to change cmd /s /c to cmd /k

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς yeah indeed I forgot to add a question. I added it. You mention shell script, does this actually run in shell script? I didn't quite understand why the registry key has shell in it. Anyways I tried changing `cmd /s /c` to `cmd /k`. It still doesn't work and no CMD window pops up at all. I don't know how to check if the cmd process actually starts or not.

Comment: You can try to check it by using taskmgr, and I am in China am it is late now, so I am going to sleep soon.

Comment: I'm not that batch literate, having formerly used .vsb files to automate tasks and then transitioning to **PowerShell**, so I'm not sure how `%d` functions here. But in terms of context menu commands, the Shell is tries to expand its variables before passing the arguement to cmd.exe. If you test a simple context command, `powershell  -NoExit -Command "'%d' | echo"`, under both `Directory\Background\Shell` and `Directory\Shell`, you'll see that the ***Background*** version errors out. Examing existing `Directory\Background` entries shows `%V` correctly expands to the folder path.

Comment: @KeithMiller I tried `%%d` instead of `%d` and it worked. Thanks!